# How to use Case or Coalesce to check if column is NULL in WHERE statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to place case or coalesce with a where statement to check if a value is null? In the example below, if the payroll table is null then the query doesn't work.

```
    @EmployeeID varchar (10)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Employee.FirstName, HRTable.Social, PayrollTable.Sallary
    FROM 
        Employee AS Employee
    LEFT JOIN 
        HRTable AS HRTable ON Employee.ID = HRTable.ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        PayrollTable AS PayrollTable ON PayrollTable.ID = HRTable.ID
    WHERE 
        (Employee.ID = @EmployeeID) 
        AND (PayrollTable.ID = @EmployeeID)
END
```

Here is what I need to say:

```
WHERE 
    (Employee.ID = @EmployeeID AND IF PayrollTable.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 
PayrollTable.ID = @EmployeeID)
```

of course that doesn't work so I'm assuming CASE or Coalesce should be used but since it's not needed in the SELECT statement I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: `IF A THEN B` => `A IMPLIES B` => `NOT A OR B` => `(Employee.ID = @EmployeeID AND (PayrollTableID IS NULL OR PayrollTable.ID = @EmployeeID)`.

Comment: Why do you need to check if `PayrollTable.ID` is `null`?

Comment: Using `COALESCE` (or `ISNULL`, or many other functions) in your `WHERE` against your column is actually a bad idea. It'll cause your query to become non-SARGable, meaning that the indexes won't be used and performance will be far from optimal.

Comment: Why not simply add "PayrollTable.ID = @EmployeeID" to your join predicate to PayrollTable and remove that part from your where clause? Also, the idea of an alias is to use a different name. If you give the alias the same name as the table all you are doing is typing more.

Comment: Something does not make any sense. If Employee.ID = _EmployeeID and Employee.ID = HRTable.ID and HRTable.ID = PayrollTable.ID then by default PayrollTable.ID = _EmployeeID. There seems to be no reason to add that criterion to your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you could simplify this a bit to something along these lines. Notice how not everything is crammed on the left so it is easier to see what is going on. And the aliases remove tons of typing and make it easier to read.

```
SELECT Employee.FirstName
    , hrt.Social
    , pt.Sallary
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN HRTable hrt ON e.ID = hrt.ID
LEFT JOIN PayrollTable pt ON pt.ID = e.ID
                        AND pt.ID = @EmployeeID
WHERE e.ID = @EmployeeID
```

Comment: Why not just `e.ID = pt.ID`?